# Unnecessary border shown when clicked content area on understrap theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm developing wordpress theme using Understrap, with using customstrap child theme of livecanvas. It uses Bootstrap 4.

I developed my theme, but there is unnecessary border when I clicked the content area on theme. I checked the code on browser using inspects but i could not find the code that caused this problem.

here is understrap repo: https://github.com/understrap/understrap

and my page.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header();

$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );

?>

<div class="wrapper" id="page-wrapper">

    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container ); ?>" id="content" tabindex="-1">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Do the left sidebar check -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'global-templates/left-sidebar-check' ); ?>

            <main class="site-main" id="main">

                <?php
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'page' );


                }
                ?>

            </main><!-- #main -->

            <!-- Do the right sidebar check -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'global-templates/right-sidebar-check' ); ?>

        </div><!-- .row -->

    </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!-- #page-wrapper -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

**Which selector that I need to use to prevent this problem?**

Here is the image of this be like:

1- 1st image is Default

2- 2nd image When I clicked the content area

[image: Default Image]
[image: When I clicked the content area]

When I clicked the content area

Comment: Does this happen in Chrome only? Like only recently too? https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html

Comment: pretty sure related to :focus somewhere

Comment: Note related to :focus selector, I tried many times. or I could not find. @TemaniAfif

Comment: It happens in all of browsers. Just with different colors @j08691

Comment: In that case we'll need to see some code. A [mcve] in your question please

Comment: I edited my post, added understrap repo and my page.php codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is `outline` property in CSS.

As we cannot see your code right now, for debugging I would suggest to try pasting this in your styles to check if that helps:

```css
* {
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I edited my post, added understrap repo and my page.php codes

Comment: Also I tried these codes, i added them into my css and it does not work

Comment: @YMG How about `box-shadow: none !important` ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code there `tabindex` is used for keyboard accessibility. `:focus` is triggered Where `tabindex` is used.

`<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container ); ?>" id="content" tabindex="-1">`

The `div` mentioned above has an id `content` so if you'd like to remove outline only from there use the following CSS code.

`#content { outline: none !important; }`.

Don't use asterisk with `:focus` like `*:focus` to solve this then that might also remove outline from some other styles.

Answer (score 0):

When I add the code below to custom css in wordpress:

```
*:focus{outline: none !important;}
```

It works.

But I don't understand that why it does not work when I add it into style.css